# Why doesn't my React components list get messed up when using Index as a key prop?

Tags: reactjs, dom, components, rendering

I have found some information online, which is saying that you shouldn't use the `index` parameter as the `key` prop when using a map. For example:

```
{myPersonsState.map( (person, index) => {
    return <Person key={index} />
})
```

According to what I've found, this is **not** good.

The reason for that, is, whenever you manipulate data in the state ***(for example, removing the 3rd element in the array)***, the key for each element, starting from the 3rd position, will **definitely** change, because each element's key is it's index (which definitely changes), and by that, React will consider the new element's keys as the old ones (before the change).

By that logic, its only logical to think that React will take the new elements starting from the 3rd position, and give them the old keys, which will consider them as the old ones - which will cause React to think it doesn't need to create a new instance of them, and just use the previous elements data to create them.

So, why do I not see that when actually manipulating the state and re-rendering ?

Why does React know that it is a new element on it's own, even though, it has another element's previous key ?

Answer (score 1):

React's key prop gives you the ability to control component instances. Each time React renders your components, it's calling your functions to retrieve the new React elements that it uses to update the DOM. If you return the same element types, it keeps those components/DOM nodes around, even if all* the props changed.

Key prop allows you to return the exact same element type, but force React to unmount the previous instance, and mount a new one. This means that all state that had existed in the component at the time is completely removed and the component is "reinitialized" for all intents and purposes. For components, this means that React will run cleanup on effects (or componentWillUnmount), then it will run state initializers (or the constructor) and effect callbacks (or componentDidMount).

Comment: So by that logic, it means that I can use the Index as the key props, and It will be just fine, no issues. Is that correct ?

Comment: There can be issues with using index as key but notice I am saying we can get issues but not always. If we are not adding /removing items from list then it is fine to use index as keys else it will be good to use some id which uniquely identifies the item. Reason is if you add or remove some items from the list, indexes change for older items and react can get confused which items are changed. But if you use state value as a list, if the state is changed, it's reinitialized and no problem about that.